# The new introduced EulerMatrix problem

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, geometry, rotation

In the present version of *Mathematica*, there is a new command

```
EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}])// MatrixForm
```

I read its document and I still don't understand it. For me, the result should be the inverse of `EulerMatrix` based on the same convention. See [this](http://www.ccp14.ac.uk/ccp/web-mirrors/klaus_eichele_software/klaus/nmr/conventions/euler/euler.html#4).

Update:

Problem for me is, for the Euler rotation, we are rotating the coordinate system. (α, β, γ) is to describe rotations or relative orientations of orthogonal coordinate systems. I think the Euler rotation should be

```
  Dot[RotationMatrix[-γ, {0, 0, 1}],
      RotationMatrix[-β, {0, 1, 0}],
      RotationMatrix[-α, {0, 0, 1}]]// MatrixForm
```

`RotationMatrix[α, {0, 0, 1}]` is the rotation of α for z in counterclockwise and active way. But we are rotating the Z axis, which is equivalent to the passive transformation. So we use -α in `RotationMatrix[-α, {0, 0, 1}]`.
This is consistent with the [this](http://www.ccp14.ac.uk/ccp/web-mirrors/klaus_eichele_software/klaus/nmr/conventions/euler/euler.html#4).

Comment: In any case, the description "rotating α around the current z axis, then β around the current y axis, and then γ around the current z axis" in the docs seems to be off, since `EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}] == RotationMatrix[α, {0, 0, 1}].RotationMatrix[β, {0, 1, 0}].RotationMatrix[γ, {0, 0, 1}]`, which implies the reverse ordering. `RollPitchYawMatrix[{α, β, γ}, {3, 2, 3}]` seems to be the correct ordering.

Comment: @J.M.: I think the behavior is consistent with the documentation because it states rotating about the "current" axes, which I assume to mean the axes in the local frame (a.k.a. body frame), rather than the world axes which is what you are using.

Comment: @Rahul, I'm still confused. If "rotating α around the current z axis" is the first step, then one is looking at `RotationMatrix[α, {0, 0, 1}]` being applied first to the vectors being acted on, no? But the current definition applies it last. What am I missing here?

Comment: see the note about active vs passive rotations on the linked site and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation . I believe mathematica is giving the active form and the linked site the passive.  In any case the mathematica description is *weak*  "rotating α around"? surely we are not rotating  α, rather rotating *something* "by"  α.

Comment: "active vs passive rotations" Ah right, that's what those things are called. Thanks @george2079!

Comment: I agree with @Rahul, in that the angles have the correct sign given the description in the documentation.

Comment: @george2079   Yes, the EulerMatrix, RotationMatrix are giving the active form. But why WignerD in Mma is passive way, which is the matrix element of euler rotation. This kind of inconsistent can lead to erros in some calculations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To verify that the rotations happen the way they're supposed to according to the documentation for [`EulerMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EulerMatrix.html), you could use the following `Manipulate`:

```
Clear[arrowAxes]; 
arrowAxes[arrowLength_: 1] := 
 Map[{Apply[RGBColor, #], Arrow[Tube[{-#, #}]]} &, 
  arrowLength IdentityMatrix[3]]

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[arrowAxes[.7], 
    EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}]], arrowAxes[]}, 
  Background -> LightGray, Boxed -> False, 
  PlotLabel -> Framed[
   Row[{"α = ", α, ", β = ", β, ", γ = ", γ}]], LabelStyle -> Larger],
 {α, 0, Pi}, {β, 0, Pi}, {γ, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: what is arrowAxes ?  It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. Now it's in.